# Flutter - TextField: No MaterialLocalizations found

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make a screenshot of a TextField including its content. I created a function that returns the TextField wrapped in `Material`. This function is called in the class to view the TextField and allow the user to enter its content. Then in the `onPressed() of a floating button in the same class I tried making the screenshot.

The textField is viewed in the application but when I click the button, I get the `No MaterialLocalizations found` error.

**If I replaced `TextField` with `Text` it works without problems. I don't know how to make it work with `TextField`??**

Here is the code:

```
class TextFromUserState extends State<TextFromUser> {
  Uint8List? bytes;

  Widget _buildTextField() {
    return Material(
      child: Container(
        child: TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            fillColor: Colors.grey[300],
            filled: true,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Read User input")),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          _buildTextField(),
          if (this.bytes != null) Image.memory(this.bytes!),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
        label: Text('Capture'),
        onPressed: () async {
          final controller = ScreenshotController();
          final bytes =
              await controller.captureFromWidget(_buildTextField());
          setState(() => this.bytes = bytes);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Widget _buildTextField() {
    return 
       Container(
        child: Localizations(
      locale: const Locale('en', 'US'),
      delegates: const <LocalizationsDelegate<dynamic>>[
        DefaultWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        DefaultMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      child: MediaQuery(
        data: const MediaQueryData(),
        child: Directionality(
          textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
          child: Material(
            child: TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            fillColor: Colors.grey[300],
            filled: true,
          ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
));
```

i guess there is no MaterialLocalizations widget in the widget tree, which textfeild required must you can give MaterialLocalization of your own like i added above, for detail you can visit [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/text-field-material-localizations)